# Pixel filter HTML elements CSS

Tags: html, css, filter, pixel

I'm creating a game using WebGL. I'm currently working on menu design, and it occured to me that one of the great advantages I have in using web technologies is that I can use HTML for the GUI.

The game uses pixel art, so in keeping with that art style I want the menu to have pixelated buttons and text as well. I'm wondering if using CSS filters or something similar I'm able to pixelate my rendering of DOM elements, or if I'll need to create full button images beforehand (much less appealing).

Thanks!

Comment: Text would be tricky, because the browsers work very hard these days to make text as readable as possible! Maybe you can use bitmapped fonts? No idea how to deliver those though; `@fontface` won't work. The borders around buttons aren't too difficult, something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sx4o1w73/1/) maybe?

Comment: That's a nice little trick right there- I wouldn't have thought of it. I was kinda hoping there would be something like `transform: scale(2)` and I could just turn off anti-aliasing. Oh well. :(